# HPA Kills the pod after a while: But container is processing some launch script

Tags: google-cloud-platform, magento, google-kubernetes-engine, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

I am trying to enable HPA for the Magento application, which consists of 4 containers in my Kubernetes deployment on GKE. The way application works do not seem to be a good container native application. Hence, after launching the pod it takes 8+mins to be in running state during which it launches a shell script from phpfpm container that takes into account some updates. This is critical for the application to work.

So if I use hpa based on default metric like CPU or memory, the autoscaling kicked in and it attempts to create more replica. But after around 4mins30seconds, the pod is killed automatically and a new pod is attempted to spin up which is again killed after that period.

So is there anyway I can have the HPA process wait for 8-9 mins which is too long, but due to current business case I have no other option?

My deployment yaml file:

If I increase the replica count manually it works perfectly. So it means the hpa kills the pod.

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: magentoappli
  annotations:
    cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict: "true"
  labels:
    environment: "test"
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: magentoappli
  replicas: 2

  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate

  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: magentoappli
        
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: magento-sa
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10

      volumes:        
        - name: phpfpm-configmap
          configMap:
            name: phpfpm
            items:
              - key: php
                path: php
              - key: phpfpm
                path: phpfpm

        - name: cluster-credentials
          secret:
            secretName: cluster-credentials
          
        - name: non-prod-magento-netapp-static-claim
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: non-prod-magento-netapp-static-claim

        - name: non-prod-magento-netapp-media-claim
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: non-prod-magento-netapp-media-claim

      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1000
        runAsGroup: 1000
        fsGroup: 1000
        runAsNonRoot: true
        seccompProfile:
          type: RuntimeDefault

      initContainers:
        - image: gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:326.0.0-alpine
          name: workload-identity-initcontainer
          command:
            - /bin/bash
            - -c
            - |
              curl -s -H 'Metadata-Flavor: Google' 'http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token' --retry 30 --retry-connrefused --retry-max-time 30 > /dev/null || exit 1

          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "128Mi"
              cpu: "100m"
            limits:
              memory: "256Mi"
              cpu: "200m"
          securityContext:
            runAsNonRoot: true
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
            seccompProfile:
              type: RuntimeDefault

        - name: nfs-fixer
          image: alpine
          securityContext:
            #runAsUser: 0
            #runAsGroup: 0
            #fsGroup: 0
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
            seccompProfile:
              type: RuntimeDefault            
          volumeMounts:
            - name: non-prod-magento-netapp-static-claim
              mountPath: /static
            - name: non-prod-magento-netapp-media-claim
              mountPath: /media
          command:
            - sh
            - -c
            - (chmod 0775 /media /static; chown -R 1000:1000 /media /static)


      containers:
        - name: phpfpm
          image: xxx/phpfpm:non-prod-1.50.104

          command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - environmental/entrypoint.sh
          securityContext:
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
            #readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
            runAsNonRoot: true
            seccompProfile:
              type: RuntimeDefault
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9000
          livenessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
              - php
              - /var/www/html/magento/bin/magento
            initialDelaySeconds: 15
            periodSeconds: 15
            timeoutSeconds: 15
          volumeMounts:
            - name: non-prod-magento-netapp-static-claim
              mountPath: /var/www/html/magento/pub/static
            - name: non-prod-magento-netapp-media-claim
              mountPath: /var/www/html/magento/pub/media

            - name: phpfpm-configmap
              mountPath: /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
              subPath: php
              readOnly: true
            - name: phpfpm-configmap
              mountPath: /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf
              subPath: phpfpm
              readOnly: true

          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: cluster-credentials

          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "768Mi"
              cpu: "2000m"
            limits:
              memory: "3072Mi"
              cpu: "4000m"

        - name: httpd
          image: xxx/httpd:non-prod-1.50.104
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
          securityContext:
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
            #runAsNonRoot: true
            #readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
            seccompProfile:
              type: RuntimeDefault
          volumeMounts:
            
            - name: non-prod-magento-netapp-static-claim
              mountPath: /var/www/html/magento/pub/static
              readOnly: true

            - name: non-prod-magento-netapp-media-claim
              mountPath: /var/www/html/magento/pub/media
              readOnly: true

          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "256Mi"
              cpu: "500m"
            limits:
              memory: "768Mi"
              cpu: "750m"

          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              port: 8000
              path: /health_check.php
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 15
            timeoutSeconds: 30
            
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              port: 8000
              path: /health_check.php
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 15
            timeoutSeconds: 30

        - name: cloudsql-proxy
          image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.31.2

          command:
            - "/cloud_sql_proxy"
            - "-ip_address_types=PRIVATE"
            - "-instances=GCP_PROJECT:region:db-name=tcp:db_port"
            - "-verbose=false"
            - "-log_debug_stdout=true"

          securityContext:
            #runAsNonRoot: true
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
            #readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
            seccompProfile:
              type: RuntimeDefault

          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "50Mi"
              cpu: "50m"
            limits:
              memory: "100Mi"
              cpu: "100m"
```

HPA:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: magento-hpa
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: magentoappli
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 10
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 85
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: You appear to be creating resource-starved containers. What steps/actions are causing such a long startup time? That is what you must reduce. I forget, but I think the startup time must be under four minutes.

Comment: Can you share the cluster autoscaler logs as well as the events from the HPA?